# Java Applet deployment to multiple JRE

Tags: java, deployment, applet

Folks,

I have the following challenge, I would like to deploy an Applet which relies on Java 1.8 syntax into hundreds of client workstations already running an old Java Applet which relies on Java 1.5

The problem is, I do not have access to the Java 1.5 Applet code and even not to it's launcher Html page. Alas, this launcher Html page relies on the Applet tag and will therefore attempts to load the most recent Java plugin version installed on the workstation.
I don't like to rely on any virtualization solution, I have to run as a Java Applet, perhaps Web Start can be considered if you think it would help.

My questions are:
Is there a local workstation configuration/hack to tell the browser to load a specific (old) Java version when rendering the Applet tag ?
Otherwise, is there a way to use Java Web Start to workaround this problem and somehow run my newer Java Applet without updating the "official" workstation Java plugin version ?

Comment: Why do you want to use the old JRE? Old applet will run perfectly with newer JRE. (Obviously this is incorrect for new applet and old JRE).

Comment: Because the old Applets are unsigned and are incompatible with the new security standards set by newer Java versions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you ask several questions, here are some answers:

1. It is not possible to run Java 1.8 code with a "lower" JRE/JDK like 1.7, 1.6 or 1.5. The other way around however is possible - you can use Java 1.8 to run a java 1.5 applet...
2. You don't need to hack your workstation - if you only install one java version (even if it is an older one) and it is installed/configured correctly that version will be used to start your applet
3. With the next generation plugin (introduced since [6u10](http://java.com/faqnewplugin)) it is possible to start your applets with a jnlp file. The [jnlp syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html) allows you to specify a specific java version and if that one is not installed it will/can be downloaded. One example would be:

   <j2se version="1.6.0_10" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>

Some general idea, please correct me if I didn't fully understand you:

You want both applets to run, right?
For that to work you will have to change something at some point. Possibilities (My answer disregards security - from this perspective always use the latest java version):

1. Install the latest Java 1.8 and sign your old applet. Signing an applet doesn't require the source code - just access your webpage, run the applet and then search java cache for the applet.jar. Sign it with an official certificate and deploy it on your server. (Additionally this may require adding some Manifest attributes as well)
2. Downgrade your new applet to java 1.7 or 1.6 and install an older Java like 1.7.0_17. [Until Java 1.7.0_21](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/java-code-signing-1915323.html) signing was not mandatory. If you see the [baseline](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u17-relnotes-1915289.html) for Java 6 it would be version 1.6.0_43.
3. Theoretically you can use jnlp to define an exact java version which should be used to run an applet. The problem is, that it was introduced starting with 1.6.0_10 - thus your 1.5 java does not suffice. If it is possible to run your old applet with a slightly newer java and also add a jnlp file to your webpage then it could work. For that you would need to: Install two newer java versions: One 1.6.0_10 or higher (until 1.6.0_43, or 1.7_17) and the latest 1.8.0_X. Then in the jnlp file define your exact 1.6/1.7 java. When accessing your web page the 1.8 plugin will be started which detects that an older java version is required and then the older version will be started afterwards. For your newer applet the latest java will be used...